# Рекурсия array_map

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

Нужно из многомерного массива сделать одномерный.
Входной массив

```
$arr = [
            ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test1'],
            ['type' => 'nesting', 'test' => 'test2', 'new' => [
                ['type' => 'second', 'test' => 'test21'],
                ['type' => 'second', 'test' => 'test22'],
                ['type' => 'nesting', 'test' => 'test23', 'new' => [
                    ['type' => 'third', 'test' => 'test231'],
                    ['type' => 'third', 'test' => 'test232']
                ]],
            ]],
            ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test3'],
            ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test4'],
            ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test5']
        ];
```

На выходе должны получить

```
        [
            ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test1'],
            ['type' => 'second', 'test' => 'test21'],
            ['type' => 'second', 'test' => 'test22'],
            ['type' => 'third', 'test' => 'test231'],
            ['type' => 'third', 'test' => 'test232'],
            ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test3'],
            ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test4'],
            ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test5']
        ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$arr = [
    ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test1'],
    ['type' => 'nesting', 'test' => 'test2', 'new' => [
        ['type' => 'second', 'test' => 'test21'],
        ['type' => 'second', 'test' => 'test22'],
        ['type' => 'nesting', 'test' => 'test23', 'new' => [
            ['type' => 'third', 'test' => 'test231'],
            ['type' => 'third', 'test' => 'test232']
        ]],
    ]],
    ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test3'],
    ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test4'],
    ['type' => 'one', 'test' => 'test5']
];


function getTests($arr)
{
    $res = [];
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (isset($item['new']) && is_array($item['new'])) {
            $res = array_merge($res,  getTests($item['new']));
        } else {
            $res[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
$tests = getTests($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Решил:

```php
$arrRes = [];

$func = function ($item) use (&$func, &$arrRes) {
  if ('nesting' === $item['type']) {
  
    return array_map($func, $item['new']);
  }

  return $arrRes[] = $item;
};

array_map($func, $arr);
```

`$arrRes` и будет выходным массивом

Comment: Тот кто поставил "-1". Сделай лучше

Comment: Ставил не я, но почему - понятно. В этом решении структура массива не та, что в условии.